# Публикация в контакте товаров на стене группы (API)

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Может кто занимался такой проблемой:
Есть группа(страница) VK.
В этой группе я размещаю через API товары.
Теперь я хочу размещать посты на стене группы некоторых размещенных товаров: например, товары со скидкой.
Т.е. методом wall.post разместить товар с фотографией и подписью на стене этой группы(по аналогии с кнопкой "поделиться" в товаре)
При использовании wall.post выдает ошибку 100. Путем эксперимента выяснил, что ошибка возникает при указании id фотографии, которая берется из товара.
Собственно вопрос: как можно использовать уже загруженное фото в товары для размещения на стене этой же группы не загружая его методами getWallUploadServer/saveWallPhoto?

Answer (score 1):

Этого не получится сделать, ранее был способ сделать это через метод `photos.getById`, получив данные от строки `secret_key`, но так как VK ограничил доступ.

Поэтому для начала делаем запрос по идентификатору к товару, получаем его больший размер, скачиваем, и загружаем уже на сервер через методы `photos.getWallUploadServer` и потом `photos.saveWallPhoto`

Comment: Это понятно. Техподдержка ответила примерно в том же ключе. Ну неудобно очень. Ведь картинка уже загружена и получается, что ее придется опять загружать. Все равно спасибо.

Comment: Ну это же наш родной ВК, когда-нибудь запилят такое)